# How do I write to separate column in Excel using UFT API

Tags: c#, hp-uft, uft-api

[HP UFT API Test - Saving Response/Checkpoint values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916128/hp-uft-api-test-saving-response-checkpoint-values)

I was facing the same challenge and found the above thread but, I am trying to figure out the below.

How can I print different response values in a separate column in Excel.

I have 4 responses I was able to add the first one and it shows up properly in excel.

When I added the second response value it prints in either the same cell or if I put both response vaules in a seperate line it prints in a seperate cell but in one row and I need each response to print in it's seperate column.

```
ID | PersonName | Address | ZipCode
```

When you go to Write to File under property Tab there is only one field for Content so I can add muiltiple outputs under Expressions but, they all export in a same row.

I am working with Rest and Json UFT-API version 12.52

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1: @ManishChristian**

Thanks Manish. I am not able to execute the script. my sheet is located on my desktop so I am assuming that there is no need to add the sql info or connect to database.

**This is what my code looks like:**

```
string price;
price = this.CodeActivity50.Input.Amount.ToString();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
string sql = null;
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\\Users/Batman/Desktop/sendAmount.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False");
MyConnection.Open();
myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
sql = "INSERT into [Sheet1] (COLUMN1) values('" + price + "')";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MyConnection.Close();
```

**Error thrown:**

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object
>   'Sheet1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and
>   the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1' is not a local object, check your
>   network connection or contact the server administrator.

My sheet name is set to Sheet1

Comment: You will need to use **`Custom Code`** to meet your requirement. This [**link**](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/12/15/service-test-11-20-how-to-write-web-service-response-to-excel/) will help get started. You can still use info from this link even though it tells about Service Test.

Comment: My comment is too long so I am posting it below.

Comment: `"I am not able to execute the script."` Elaborate.

Comment: Is there a way to export the data using custom code without having to use the sql code provided in the link. I am trying this but getting an error:

string Store;
Store = this.CodeActivity50.Input.Amount.ToString();
GetDataSource("C:\\Users/Batman/Desktop/sendAmount.xlsx").SetValue(2,amount, Stored);
              
Error:

The name 'amount' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)

Comment: First you have to pass `Input` variable with some value to `CustomCode` and than you'll be able to access it in your `CustomCode`. Please check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30900339/1652222) on how you can pass and access variable. Same way you can pass multiple variables and access it in your code.

Comment: I was able to follow the link instructions but, how do I export the response values to excel using that where each response value is parsed in a separate column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL free way to write data to your Excel file using **`CustomCode`** in **`UFT`**.

**Assumptions:**

> - You have set all your four variables as **`Input parameter`** for your **`CustomCode`**. Here is a [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900339/1652222) on how to do that.
> - You have imported all the required contents in your CustomCode in order make this code work.

**C# Code:**

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
//  IMPORT OTHER REQURED CONTENTS

//  CHANGE THESE VARIABLES AS PER YOUR NEED
//  ALSO CHANGE WS_Method_Type, WS_Method_Name, sEnvironment, TestDataSet_Val  
//  FROM BELOW LINES AS PER YOUR INPUT VARIABLE NAMES
String wsMethodType     = this.CodeActivity16.Input.WS_Method_Type.ToString();
String wsMethodName     = this.CodeActivity16.Input.WS_Method_Name;
String env              = this.CodeActivity16.Input.sEnvironment;
String testDataSetVal   = this.CodeActivity16.Input.TestDataSet_Val.ToString();

String sheetName        = "Sheet1";
String srcFile          = @"PATH \ TO \ YOUR \ XLSX \ FILE";

Excel.Application xlApp = null;
Excel.Workbook wb       = null;
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
Excel.Range excelCell   = null;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
//xlApp.Visible = true;     //  UN-COMMENT ME TO SEE EXCEL
if (xlApp == null)
{
    CodeActivity16.Report("Excel error","Excel could not be started");
}

//  OPENING EXCEL TO WRITE THE DATA     
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(srcFile,
                                   0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                                   true, false, 0, true, false, false);
worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[sheetName];

int lastUsedRow = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell,Type.Missing).Row;

//  LET'S WRITE INPUT VARIABLE VALUES TO COLUMN A:D IN LAST ROW
//  CHANGE IT AS PER YOUR NEED
excelCell       = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("A" + lastUsedRow, "A" + lastUsedRow);
excelCell.Value = wsMethodType;

excelCell       = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("B" + lastUsedRow, "B" + lastUsedRow);
excelCell.Value = wsMethodName;

excelCell       = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("C" + lastUsedRow, "C" + lastUsedRow);
excelCell.Value = env;

excelCell       = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("D" + lastUsedRow, "D" + lastUsedRow);
excelCell.Value = testDataSetVal;

wb.Save();
xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
xlApp.Quit();
```

**Note:**

You need to add some error handling and clean-up code as this is not final code.